# access xampp virtual hosts from virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, hosts, virtualization

My host is Ubuntu and guest is Windows XP.
I'm also running Xampp on Ubuntu with a bunch of virtual hosts.
For example I have a host named "ehpc.loc" binded to 127.0.0.7 ip-address.
So I need to access this host from guest Windows XP.

I know that I can access localhost via http://10.0.2.2/. But it only shows a site binded to 127.0.0.1. What I need is to access a site binded to 127.0.0.7.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should set up the virtual network adapters in 'bridged' mode.  Than the virtual guests will get IP addresses via the same method as the host, and be visible to each other like any other machine on your network.